# REGEXEXTRACT before a character

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a small regex to extract the text before an optional `(`.

I have this:

```
^(.*)[\(.*]|$
```

But its not working for some reason. Doesn't seem to make it to the `$` if there is no `(` present.

Any help would be much appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex will either capture 0+ times any character in a capturing group `(.*)` followed by a character class matching one of the listed characters `[\(.*]`,  or it will match an empty string due to the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|$`.

If the first part of the alternation does not match a character from the character class at the end, you will not have a match.

You could use a negated character class to match not a `(` from the start of the string:

`^[^(]+`

Comment: Great. Thanks. That's got it. Just need to escape the ( in your answer.

Comment: @ChrisBarrett It works without escaping the `(` as it is used inside a bracket expression/character class.